# Error in limma - lmFit - chol2inv: 'x' must be a square numeric matrix

Tags: r, bioconductor

I couldn't find an answer to this, so I'm posting the solution in case others have the same issue.

Using the limma package from Bioconductor, I had the following error:

```
> fit <- try(lmFit(matrix, design))
Error in chol2inv(fit$qr$qr, size = fit$qr$rank) : 
  'x' must be a square numeric matrix
```

Not a very helpful error message, but the problem is simple. The rownames of your "matrix" cannot have any duplicates. Check this with

```
any(duplicated(rownames(matrix)))
```

and rename the rows if necessary.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but the rowname duplication check doesn't fix the very similar error I got.

Comment: @DirtStats If you want help on your problem, you should give the error message and a reproducible code snippet so others can help you!

Comment: Thanks @sssheridan.  I worked around my problem with a similar error.  I was just posting that comment so others would know that the error mentioned above could have other sources, too.

Answer (score 1):

The rownames of your "matrix" cannot have any duplicates. Check this with

```
any(duplicated(rownames(matrix)))
```

and rename the rows if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The limma package `lmFit()` function does make several calls to the base `chol2inv` function.

Following some packages update on my Windows R3.2.5 environment, a similar error occurred on my side when passing a matrix object to the `lmFit()` function. Installing R version 3.3.1 (again under Windows OS) did solve the problem: passing a matrix object to `lmFit()` (Limma 3.26.9)  did return a `MArrayLM` object as expected, without "complains" from the `chol2inv` function.

An upgrade to R 3.3.1 "Bug in Your Hair" might hopefully solve other `lmFit()` issues.